# Prove if statements are ligically equivalent

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is P(A)∪P(B) = P(A∪B) true for all sets of A and B? If so prove it?

How do I prove this? I am not showing any attempt because I do not know how to even begin this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @Hayden I am assuming it is the power set.

Comment: @Budge Ah, that makes much more sense!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Assuming by $P(A)$ and $P(B)$ you mean the power set of $A,B$, actually test this with some actual sets.  We need not go far to spot trouble; try $A=\{0\}$ and $B=\{1\}$.

Answer (score 0):

Reason like this: if $x \in P(A)\cup P(B)$ ... (your argument) ... then $x \in P(A\cup B)$.

And vice versa.

In general, set equalities are often easiest to prove by showing that the subset inclusion holds in both directions.

Comment: Although keep in mind in this case that the subset inclusion actually only holds in one direction.